# If A and B are symmetric is AB=BA true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

### Question

if we have matrices $A$ and $B$ which are symmetric. Both of these satisfy:
$$  A=A^T$$
Is $AB=BA$ true ?

### Attempt to solve

Now if $A$ and $B$ are symmetric then $AB$ most be symmetric too.

$$ AB=(AB)^T=B^TA^T=BA $$

problem is how do you proof that if $A$ and $B$ are symmetric also $AB$ is symmetric ?

If somone could provide some insight on this that would ge highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Tuki

Comment: The product of symmetric matrices is not always symmetric, though.

Comment: So it isn't true that if $A$ and $B$ are symmetric that $AB$ would be also symmetric ? hence $AB$=$BA$ might not be true ?

Comment: -1 for the lack of efforts. It is easy to generate a counterexample by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not always true. Consider, for instance, the matrices
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix},\quad B = \pmatrix{0 & 1\\1 & 0}
$$
where 
$$
AB = \pmatrix{0 & 1\\2 & 0},\quad BA = \pmatrix{0 & 2\\1&0}
$$
are not equal, and not symmetric.

Answer (score 6):

Let $$A =\begin {bmatrix} a & b\\ b & c \end {bmatrix} \quad\mbox{and}\quad B = \begin {bmatrix} d & e\\ e & f \end {bmatrix}$$
be two symmetric matrices. Then 
$$AB-BA =\begin {bmatrix} ad+be & ae + bf\\ bd+ec & be + cf\end {bmatrix} -\begin {bmatrix} ad +be & db + ec\\ ea+bf & eb + fc\end {bmatrix}=\begin {bmatrix} 0 & ?\\ ? & 0\end {bmatrix}.$$
Is the right-hand side necessarily the zero matrix?

Answer (score 0):

In general we do not have that $A,B$ symmetric implies that $AB$ is symmetric.

But the following is true: Let $A,B$ symmetric. Then

$AB$ is symmetric $ \iff AB=BA$.

Try a proof !

Comment: This is easiest proven using simultaneous diagonalisability. Not sure if that's the level the OP is on. I could be wrong, though.

Answer (score -3):

If $A$ and $B$ are symmetric matrices then $AB=(BA)^T$, so only if $AB$ is symmetric is it true that $AB=BA$.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Math.SE. It would be helpful if you learn to use the MathJax capabilities of this site. It makes your post prettier and more easily understandable. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference