# When is $A^TR + RA = -2RA$

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetry, positive-definite, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

I am working through some exercises on stability theory and Lyapunov analysis.

The equation in question is

\begin{equation}
A^TR+RA = -I.
\end{equation}

The matrix $A_{n\times n}$ is symmetric, Hurwitz (all eigenvalues have a negative real part) and $R_{n\times n}$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix. The matrix $I_{n\times n}$ is denoting the identity matrix.

Because $A$ is symmetric it is claimed that the previous equation can be restated as

$$2RA = -I.$$

It is easy to come up with counterexamples to show that symmetry alone is not sufficient.

It is obvious that the equation can be rewritten as

$$AR + RA = -I.$$

If both matrices would commute than the claim would be easy to verify.

**Questions**

> 1. Is there a criterion to check if two matrices / symmetric matrices commute?
> 2. What additional conditions (including symmetry of $A$) would be sufficient to guarantee that $A^TR + RA = -I \implies 2RA = -I$?

Comment: 1. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2490623/if-a-and-b-are-symmetric-is-ab-ba-true), the answer by Fred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is there a criterion to check if two matrices / symmetric matrices commute?

It is a hard problem to find a criterion that works all the time and is easier than just checking both products. However, here is one:

**Theorem.** If $A$, $B$ are symmetric then $AB=BA$ if and only if $AB$ is also symmetric.

A [proof here](http://web.mst.edu/~insall/courses/linalg1/Solved%20Problems/Matrix%20Products/Problem_2.pdf) for instance.

> 2. What additional conditions (including symmetry of $A$) would be sufficient to guarantee that $A^TR + RA = -I \implies 2RA = -I$?

If $A$ is symmetric then the implication $$A^TR + RA = -I \implies 2RA = -I$$ is *equivalent* to $$AR=RA$$
therefore I don't think there can be more to be said in this direction.

Comment: +1: Thank you for your answer, helped me a lot. I will wait to see If someone comes up with an alternative criterion and then accept the better answer :).